# fnmatch usage with complicate pattern C

Tags: c, posix, fnmatch

I'm only able to match simple patterns like: `"[0-9]"` with `fnmatch("[0-9]", tocheck, 0)`.

If I try something more complicated with `?` or `.` or even a combination of these how do I use [`fnmatch`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html)?
I saw there are some flags that can do the trick, but I don't know how to use because I'm fairly new to C.

EDIT: I saw the comment asking to give more details:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fnmatch.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const char *patternOne = "[0-9]";
    const char *patternTwo = ".?[a-z0-9]*?*[a-z0-9]";
    int res = fnmatch(patternTwo, "0", 0);
    printf("Result: %d\n",  res);
}
```

If I use `patternOne` the result is `0` and if I change the string to match, the result change correctly.
However if I use `patternTwo` I never get the `0` result for whatever string I pass to `fnmatch`.
I need to match something like this in my program. It is for an university exam, so the patterns are very intricate.

Comment: This is not a standard C function. RTFM for the library that contains fnmatch().

Comment: What is `fnmatch`?

Comment: Please give sample input, desired output and actual output for a few cases.

Comment: For reference, this is the definition of fnmatch: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Comment: If `fnmatch` is supposed to match patterns in a string, should you be using `['0'-'9']` and not `[0-9]`? Is there a similarity with `scanf`'s `%[]`specifer?

Comment: The POSIX function fnmatch matches wildcard patterns, not regular expressions. Wildcard patterns are described in glob(7): http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html .

Comment: Please provide the complete code that fails to do what you expect. A complete example of the pattern and filename you want to match against, and the flags you have passed.

Comment: You may interest yourself in [regex.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/regex.h.html).

Comment: Updated the question, I hope it is clear what I want to do.

Comment: A more direct link to the `fnmatch()` POSIX spec: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fnmatch.html

Comment: As mentioned in a couple comments here, `fnmatch()` doesn't match regular expressions.  As a quick example, the fact that `patternTwo` starts with a `'.'` character means it won't match `"0"` since for `fnmatch()` a period matches a period (not any character like in a regex).  For example, try `fnmatch(patternTwo, ".x0y1", 0)` will will show a match.

Answer (score 4):

Treat the pattern as a shell glob pattern. Given:

```
const char* patternTwo = ".?[a-z0-9]*?*[a-z0-9]";
```

There is no way `"0"` will match that. An example of a string that will match it would be: `".XaX9"`

> `.` matches `.`
>       `X` matches `?`
>       `a` matches `[a-z0-9]`
>       `X` matches `*?*`
>       `9` matches `[a-z0-9]`

The reason `fnmatch()` is different from `glob()` is so that the pattern `"*"` (which as a normal glob would match any string) will fail to match a file named `".profile"` because dot files are treated as hidden (it is function designed to perform a file name match).

Answer (score 0):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fnmatch.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const char *patternOne = "[0-9]";
    const char *patternTwo = ".?[a-z0-9]*?*[a-z0-9]";
    int res = fnmatch(patternTwo, "0", FNM_EXTMATCH);
    printf("Result: %d\n",  res);
}
```

Set **FNM_EXTMATCH** flag can use like `.?[a-z0-9]*?*[a-z0-9]` with pattern

**FNM_EXTMATCH**
Besides the normal patterns, also recognize the extended patterns introduced in ksh. The patterns are written in the form explained in the following table where pattern-list is a | separated list of patterns.

`?(pattern-list)`
The pattern matches if zero or one occurrences of any of the patterns in the pattern-list allow matching the input string.

`(pattern-list)`
The pattern matches if zero or more occurrences of any of the patterns in the pattern-list allow matching the input string.

`+(pattern-list)`
The pattern matches if one or more occurrences of any of the patterns in the pattern-list allow matching the input string.

`@(pattern-list)`
The pattern matches if exactly one occurrence of any of the patterns in the pattern-list allows matching the input string.

`!(pattern-list)`
The pattern matches if the input string cannot be matched with any of the patterns in the pattern-list.